# Using ACR Notifications to fire daily at scheduled times

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

- Currently i making a med schedule which fires a local notification everyday at the time your med is due, so far i have got it working for the first day but it will not fire again unless the user clicks on the notification.

  ```
  else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)

      {

          App.BadgeCount = App.BadgeCount + 1;
          CrossNotifications.Current.Badge = App.BadgeCount;
          Random rnd = new Random();
          string stringid = rnd.Next(1, 1000000000).ToString();
          stringid = CrossNotifications.Current.Send(usermedid, "Please take " + dosage + " of " + medname, "ding", ms);
          Debug.WriteLine("Notification saved" + stringid);
  ```

Is there any way to add in my code a way to set the notification to repeat daily at that exact time without having to click on the notification ? Would be best to revert to using UILocalNotifications and using the repeat interval ?

Any help appreciated .. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see in the ACR source it can only schedule something through tje calendar, so yes, then you will need a manual action to schedule the next one. Also, I think there is a limit to how many notifications you can schedule in the future.

You are mentioning [UILocalNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification), not that this API is deprecated as of iOS 10. You probably want to use the replacement: [UNNotificationRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest). Looking at that API, there is a function to schedule notifications with an interval and the option to let them repeat for each interval. In native code this looks like this:

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (30*60), repeats: false)
```

That is probably what you are after. So now you need to either find a plugin that supports this, or write something yourself

Comment: Thanks, changed up my code so i am now using UNNotificationRequest. If I use the calendar date trigger and i set a datetime in that , will that fire at that exact same time every day if i set repeat to true ??

Comment: If you set the time components to only be the hour and minutes, then yes.

Comment: Got it , thanks. Is there a way you can cancel all the notifications at once using this , eg when the user logs out ?

Comment: You probably need the `removeAllPendingNotificationRequests` for that

Comment: Can you restore them as well once you log back in ?

Comment: No, then you will have to schedule them again